# IntelliJ IDEA non standard caret behaviour

Tags: intellij-idea, selection, caret

I have an issue with IntelliJ IDEA when selecting a big amount of text, and I cannot find the parameter to set to change that. Here is an example of the situation:

1. My caret is on line 3
2. I scroll with the mouse wheel towards line 300
3. I press ctrl + shift
4. I press the left button of the mouse

Such an action would result in the text from line 3 to 300 being selected in all common editors (even in MS-Word I think), but not in IntelliJ.

Do you know how to set this right?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `ctrl`+`shift`? `Shift` is enough to select those lines in most editors, `ctrl` is most commonly used to add additional items (for example, two ranges with `shift`).

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Left Click` is "Navigate to Type Declaration" in IDEA. See [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/ctrl+shift.html).

Comment: Waw I feel a bit stupid right now, I did not know ctrl was useless for this operation. Actually it works with ctrl in all editors but not in Intellij...  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah they probably do not have `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Left Click` binded anywhere like IDEA does. You can change it in keymappings though if you wish to.